# Project not running in myeclipse

Tags: myeclipse

I copied the project(folder) into the myeclipse environment folder and when i try to run it , it is giving the following error :

> Problems occurred opening the selected resources.
>
> The project description file (**.project**) for 'activity tracker' is missing.  This file contains important information about the project.  The project will not function properly until this file is restored.

`activity tracker` is the name of the project

How do i generate this file ?

i am currently running
**MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench Version: 8.6**

Answer (score 0):

Delete the project from the workspace but don't delete the project files on disk (this is an option during the delete process). Then create a project, of the appropriate type, with the same name, in the same location (defaulted to the workspace). I'm not sure if you'll be prompted to reuse the files already in the project location but you can play it by ear.

Alternatively, move the project to another folder. Create a new project with the same name, of the same type, and add the appropriate capabilities. Then copy your source in from the moved old project.

Tip: 8.5 is very old, consider moving to the latest release, with loads of fixes and new features.